# What is wrong with my layout code?

Tags: java, layout

So, when I start my program, my buttons get mixed up and I get a huge JButton accross whole screen. Here is the code:

```
super ("Title");

okvir = new JFrame();
okvir.setSize(1350, 768);
okvir.setLocation (0, 0);
okvir.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
okvir.setVisible(true);

sab = new JButton("sabiranje");
sab.setBounds (20 , 20 , 50 , 20);
okvir.add(sab);
od = new JButton ("oduzimanje");
od.setBounds (20 , 40 , 50 , 20);
okvir.add(od);
rez = new JLabel ("rezultat");
rez.setBounds (20 , 60 , 50 , 20);
okvir.add(rez);
x = new JTextField ("",4);
x.setBounds (20 , 80 , 50 , 20);
okvir.add(x);
y = new JTextField("",4);
y.setBounds (20 , 100 , 50 , 20);
okvir.add(y);
mnoz = new JButton("mnozenje");
mnoz.setBounds (20 , 120 , 50 , 20);
okvir.add(mnoz);
delj = new JButton ("deljenje");
delj.setBounds (20 , 140 , 50 , 20);
okvir.add(delj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're placing all the buttons in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position of the frame which not only respect referred sizes of its child components but replaces each subsequent button. Create a new panel to accomodate the buttons.

Calling setBounds will have no effect since youre using a layout manager so these statements can be deleted

Comment: thank you for the response. What should I do so that I could use .setBounds?

Comment: Don't do it! use a layout manager instead and use pack your frame to size according to preferred sizes

Comment: @vulovicv: using `setBounds(...)` and null layout is not recommended as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain. It's also a pretty good sign that the code was created by a newbie Swing coder. Instead you will want to study and learn the layout managers and then nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager to create pleasing and complex GUI's that look good on all OS's.